# Image not being displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image

need help in displaying image.I have an image called 'train' in  'app/assets/images/'

In the view I am using

```
<%= image_tag "app/assets/images/train.png" %>
```

I only get the name of the image(Train) but not the image.

I also tried

```
<%= image_tag("train.png")%>.
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the HTML tag that is output ?

Comment: Are you using the asset pipeline (rails 3.1.x)

Comment: <img alt="Train" src="/assets/train.png" />.I tried placing the image in public directory but still the same.

Comment: @Hishalv:  I have enabled the asset  'config.assets.enabled = true' in application.rb but Asset pipeline?, well not sure.

Comment: @Isabella ok so you are using asset pipeline, in your terminal under root directory try typing this "rake assets:precompile" and stick to using <%= image_tag("train.png") %>, as using the other form might cause problems for you later in production environment.

Comment: See my answer if problem persists, there are some links to tutorials that might help.

Answer (score 2):

If you have trains.png located in public/assets/images you should use:

```
<%=image_tag("images/train.png")%>.
```

If you use

```
<%= image_tag("train.png")%>
```

your train.png image is supposed to be in the assets/ folder.

Comment: You would only use app/assets if you wish your files to undergo some pre-processing before they are served. If a file exists at public/assets/rails.png it is served by the webserver.

if your file located in /app/assets it is served my Sprockets

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following statement :

```
image_tag("train.png")
```

Where `train.png` is the path after `/app/assets/images/`.

Also, make sure that the assets are compiled :

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you are using asset pipeline, in your terminal under root directory try typing this

```
rake assets:precompile
```

and stick to using

```
<%= image_tag("train.png") %>
```

, as using the other form might cause problems for you later in production environment.

If the problem persists i recommend checking out a tutorial [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1) on the asset pipeline or creating a new app [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
<%= image_tag 'image_name_with_extension' %>
```